# Why is the last else statement not printing/executing here?

Tags: java, if-statement

The last else statement won't print anything...
just takes the input and stops the program. What am I doing wrong?

I am completely new, just begun studying java. No prior experience in any code. Sorry.

Tried checking syntax everything looks ok to "me noob eyes"

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MyClass 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)

    { 
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);

        int x =7;

        System.out.println("Enter a Number from 1 to 10: ");

        int guess = scn.nextInt();

        while(x != guess) 
        {
            if(x < guess) {
            System.out.println("Guess Lower...");
            guess = scn.nextInt();
            }

            else if (x > guess) {
                System.out.println("Guess Higher...");
                guess = scn.nextInt();
            }

            else {
            System.out.println("Correct Guess!");
            }
        } 
        }

}
```

So if i enter 7
it should say/show 
Correct Guess!

but it wont show anything.

Guess low and high works fine though.

Comment: It's your `while` condition.  It breaks out of the loop before the `else` block has a chance to run.

Comment: but the last else is contained within while is it not?

Comment: @S.S. no, last else is within if, not while

Comment: oh ok so x becomes = guess and it confuses the while condition in this case which is while x is NOT eq to guess?

Comment: @S.S I think what @liya Bursov is trying to say is that the only time the last ```else``` is executed is when ```x == guess```. However' your while loop only runs while ```x != guess```.

Comment: right i understand now. **Thank you guys**

Comment: Thanks again, it works you guys are wonderful. Sorry to have you guys break it down to me in bite size pieces. 
Have a great day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the condition of while loop.
Take a look at `Recursión in Java`.
That can be done like this:

```
import java.util.*;

public class MyClass 
{

 public static void main(String []args)
 {
   new_guess();

}


static void new_guess()
{
    int correct_answer = 7;
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a Number from 1 to 10: ");
    int guess = scn.nextInt();

    if(correct_answer != guess)
    {
        if(correct_answer < guess)
        {
        System.out.println("Guess Lower...");
        }
        else if (correct_answer > guess) 
        {
            System.out.println("Guess Higher...");
        }
        new_guess();
    }
    else
    {
          System.out.println("Correct Guess!");
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Holy...I've never seen this before. Thanks for sharing, I did not understand anything but, this looks intimidating and interesting at the same time.

Comment: Recursion in java is a process in which a method calls itself continuously. It is very important to call with some condition, like in your case - method keeps calling itself while user guess is not correct.

Comment: ohoho... nice! i did not know you could do this --> new_guess();
time to study

Answer (score 1):

When correct number is compared, code escapes `while` loop immediately so last `else` statement is unreachable.

You can do what you want like below:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MyClass 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)

    { 
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);

        int x =7;

        System.out.println("Enter a Number from 1 to 10: ");

        int guess = scn.nextInt();

        while(x != guess) {
            if(x < guess) {
                System.out.println("Guess Lower...");
                guess = scn.nextInt();
            } else if (x > guess) {
                System.out.println("Guess Higher...");
                guess = scn.nextInt();
            }
        } 
        System.out.println("Correct Guess!");
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should get this code `System.out.println("Correct Guess!")` out of the loop since it will loop until it finds to be guessed value without going to next line of the code.

pl refer the code below.

```
Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);

    int x = 7;

    System.out.println("Enter a Number from 1 to 10: ");

    int guess = scn.nextInt();

    while (x != guess) {
        if (x == guess)
            System.out.println("correct");
        else if (x < guess) {
            System.out.println("Guess Lower...");
            guess = scn.nextInt();
        }

        else if (x > guess) {
            System.out.println("Guess Higher...");
            guess = scn.nextInt();
        }

    }
    System.out.println("correct");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its a while loop, it keeps running until the specified expression is false, so you don't need to introduce an else block to "confirm" the equality of the guess variable. It'll automatically print out what's next when your expression returns false.

```
    while(x != guess) 
    {
        if(x < guess) {
        System.out.println("Guess Lower...");
        guess = scn.nextInt();
        }

        else if (x > guess) {
            System.out.println("Guess Higher...");
            guess = scn.nextInt();
        }
    } 
        System.out.println("correct!");
    }
```

Essentially your code should be reformed in that manner